Using Modals in Expo
I'm pretty new to React Native, and I decided to develop a application with Expo. The main problem I'm facing right now is regarding how to use Modals in a optimal way. I want to create modals for selecting a category, and, inside that modal, add a trigger to another modal to create a category if it doesn't exist.

I'm currently using a structure like:
<Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
</Stack>

Where in the (tabs) is just two simple tabs, and in one of them I will create the modals.
Which would be the best approach for handling the nested modals?
Expo has it's file based modals, but I didn't got a grasp of how can i implement it, should I just create a structure like
<Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
      <Stack.Screen name="modal" />
      <Stack.Screen name="nestedModal" />
</Stack>

or just using the React Native Modal is a acceptable approach? The code looked kinda messy on the state handling for it. Also, I'm using BlurView for it, is it possible to achieve something like it using the Expo approach?
I'm currently implementing a straight forward approach with two modals, each one being in a separated component and having it own state, and then just using the nested one inside the other.
This approach is working with the BlurView, but the code looks unnecessarily complicated.
Thanks in advice.
